# How wireshark capture packets in LAN without arpspoof?

Tags: wireshark, arp-spoofing, packet

I created a lab environment which has Windows 7 and Kali Linux in VMware.

In Kali Linux, I opened Wireshark and started to listen to traffic on eth0. After that, in my Windows 7 machine, I opened an HTTP site and entered some login information to that site.

Wireshark was able to capture that login information.

How does Wireshark capture those packets? Windows 7 sent its packets to the router but Wireshark was able to capture them.

I didn't use arpspoof for MITM attack so I didn't trick Windows 7 into thinking the Kali machine was the gateway nor gateway as kali machine is windows 7. So my guess was Wireshark shouldn't capture those packets but it did capture them anyway.

Anybody can tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why Wireshark can capture all packets is because of the NAT environment. IN NAT, VM's in VMware will use the physical adapter. That's the NIC of my computer. So VMware provides the ethernet card to the VM's. Both Windows 7 and kali will use the same ethernet card because VMware points my ethernet card to this VM's for internet access. So when I sniff eth0 from Wireshark, because of windows 7 use the same ethernet card, all packets will be captured by the Wireshark. This lab should be done in bridged-adapter network environment. In that environment, VMware should isolate the NIC's for the VM's. So that, there is a need of arpspoofing in order to capture traffic from kali.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually not a security question at all. The question you want to be asking is how one node on a network can see the packets that are not destined for it. For this answer, you need to understand how Ethernet networking works.

Ethernet networks are broadcast networks, meaning that every node on the same segment can see every other node's traffic. No tricks required.

A switch, and a wifi access point acts like a switch, breaks up these broadcast zones (mostly) so that only the nodes that need to talk to each other see the traffic. That's why you need to arp-spoof: you need to trick the victim node to send you the traffic first and then you pass it on to the intended destination.

But without a switch, everyone can see everyone's traffic. So, your Kali's Wireshark could simply and easily see the traffic being sent by the other node. No tricks required.

Comment: So, because of my vmware environment hasn't got a switch (just router), my wireshark can sniff all packets inside that environment.Then, If I got an environment that has a switch and my victim and attacker machines are in the same VLAN, I needed to use arp-spoof to fool the Windows 7 as I am the router. So with arpspoof, I did change the mac address of router in windows 7's route table and give my mac address instead? Did I understand it correct? Or should I change the MAC address information in switch also?

Comment: You have some language errors there, but it looks like you are correct. Please do some reading on Ethernet, networking, and broadcast zones.

Comment: Hm your VMware virtual switch should also not flood its ports with packets. How many VMs you had in your lab and on which of them was Wireshark running?

Comment: Routers also break up broadcast zones. But there point is there isn't a virtual switch or router in between Kali's virtual network card, and Windows. So they get to see each others' traffic. I guess VMware did it that way for maximum reliability and performance, because they *could* have added a virtual switch.

Comment: @eckes I have 2 machines for this lab. One is windows 7 and other is kali linux.

Comment: @eckes and wireshark is running on kali

Comment: @immibis I can't find any information that VMware workstation hasn't got any virtual switches. Normally in vmware environment, there should be virtual switches that connects VMs to each other and this virtual switch should have uplinks for communication between virtual network and physical network. If Vmware workstation doesn't provide different solution for networking, there should be a virtual switch. And I guess this virtual switch is connected to virtual router which has uplinks to the physical network. If this is the case, again wireshark shouldn't sniff all packets based on the answers.

Comment: @immibis@schroeder From this document: "https://www.vmware.com/content/dam/digitalmarketing/vmware/en/pdf/techpaper/virtual_networking_concepts.pdf" I have researched that there is a virtual switch between VM's but this is for vmware environment. I dont know if vmware workstation is using different solution. So again, if there is a switch, shouldn't that switch breaks the broadcast zones?

Comment: What networking configuration do you have for those 2 VMs?

Comment: @schroeder I presume they are NAT. My laptop isn't near me. I can confirm that after I got to home.

Comment: As I said, this is not a security question but a networking question. Your question did not include any technology reference, so my answer is the technically correct answer. The details of how the virtual switch works in your implementation is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @schroeder Yes it is a network question but it is related to arpspoofing. I just dont get if there is a virtual switch and as you said if the switches breaks the broadcast zones, the wireshark shouldn't sniff all packets before I enable arpspoofing. So, it is a virtual environment security issue if we can sniff all packets in all virtual environments. I guess the virtual switches doesn't break the the broadcast zones than(I'm not sure). Anyways thank you for your information. I'll put this post to networkengineering.stackexchange as well. If there is another answer, please answer here.

Comment: But you never started the arpspoofing, so it's not a factor. Please do not cross-post on StackExchange. And this would get rejected at networkengineering.stackexchange. I'm not sure where this should go. It's more of a question for the vendor, actually.

Comment: I think security breach in here is happened because I never started arpspoofing. Arpspoof can at least be tracked. But using wireshark to capture all packets in an environment? That is the security problem I guess. Anyway, if somebody knows answer please reply. And thanks for your help @schroeder

Comment: As described here you can allow promise mode for virtual interfaces for VMs. It looks alike this will also enable hub mode on the vSwitch. So perhaps your Kali machine definition file had that enabled initially? https://superuser.com/questions/1139028/configuring-promiscuous-mode-in-vmware-workstation-running-on-windows-10-serving

Comment: @eckes That wasn't enabled at all. There is no such entry for promisc mode in vmx file.